# MySQL Stored Procedure, Insert if row doesn't exist. Select id of that row (either inserted row or pre-existing row)

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I am creating a stored procedure to register a user.
Here is the create:

`CREATE TABLE User (
    UID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Fname VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    Lname VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(32),
    Email VARCHAR(50),
    Pass VARCHAR(32),
    CONSTRAINT User_PK PRIMARY KEY(EmpID),
    CONSTRAINT User_UK1 UNIQUE (FName, LName, Phone),
    CONSTRAINT User_UK2 UNIQUE (FName, LName, Email),
    CONSTRAINT User_UK3 UNIQUE (Email, Pass)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;`

Here is the stored procedure so far:

`DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE regUser(fname VARCHAR(32),lname VARCHAR(32),phone VARCHAR(32), email VARCHAR(50), pass VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
    DECLARE uid INT;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1062 BEGIN END;
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO User(Fname, Lname, Phone, Email, Pass) VALUES(fname, lname, phone, email, pass);
        SELECT UID FROM User WHERE Phone=phone OR Email=email AND Fname=fname AND Lname=lname;
    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;`

In the stored procedure it attempts the insert, if a duplicate entry is found the continue handler(1062) catches the error and doesn't do anything. **After the insert (or lack of) I want to select the UID of the inserted row, or of the pre-existing row (if no insert was done due to duplicate)**

What is happening: The SELECT UID..WHERE... is returning a column of 4 NULL values instead of the UID of the row `WHERE Phone=phone OR Email=email AND Fname=fname AND Lname=lname;`

I believe the 4 NULL values are because I have 4 Users in the User table at the moment.

I am completely puzzled on this, if I do the SELECT UID..WHERE... outside of the stored procedure, it works just fine, returning the UID `WHERE Phone=phone...`

I get the same result NULL when inserting a User that is already in the table and when trying a new unique user.

Comment: Your probably want to put the `OR` In parenthesis.

Comment: No probably about it.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but the parenthesis didn't fix the `NULL` return values @MarcusAdams.  It's like it's trying to select a column that doesn't exist from a table it knows about so it just returns NULL for every row in the table.  Really strange.

Comment: See example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af6c04/1)